# switch statement in generating random numbers in java : not working

Tags: java, if-statement, random, switch-statement

I've used a switch statement in my code that tosses a coin and generates a random result. If the coin falls on 0, it shows tails and if it falls on 1, it shows heads. But when I'm using switch statements, the outputs are always either only "heads" or both of "tails' and "heads".

My code:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;

class generateRandomNumbers{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random coin = new Random();
        int toss;
        toss = coin.nextInt(2);
        switch(toss){
            case 0 : out.println("tails");
            case 1 ; out.println("heads");
        }
    }
}
```

But when I used if-else statements it worked as planned:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;

class generateRandomNumbers{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random coin = new Random();
        int toss;
        toss = coin.nextInt(2);
        if(toss == 0){
            out.println("tails");
        }
        else{
            out.println("heads");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: missed `break` between cases... This code wont compile.....`case1;`

Comment: add break statement after your case

Comment: oh yes! Thank you! @piyush jaiswal

Comment: @OrchoSiddiqui - please select and mark an appropriate answer to the question

Answer (score 5):

`case`s in a `switch` statement fall through if you don't terminate them (usually with a `break`, but `return`ing or `throw`ing an exception will also do the trick). In your case, when you randomly generate `0` its case is executed, and then the program just continues to the next case (`1`). You could solve this by adding `break` statements at the end of each `case`:

```
switch(toss){
    case 0 : 
        out.println("tails");
        break; // Here
    case 1 :
        out.println("heads");
        break; // And here
}
```

Additional information can be found in [Java's tutorial on the subject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try to add break

```
Random coin = new Random();
int toss;
toss = coin.nextInt(2);
switch(toss){
    case 0 : System.out.println("tails"); break;
    case 1 : System.out.println("heads"); break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though changing the code as follows helps :

```
case 0 : out.println("tails"); break;
case 1 : out.println("heads"); break;
```

But for a case like yours to deal with I would prefer using a `boolean flag` to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;

class generateRandomNumbers{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random coin = new Random();
        int toss;
        toss = coin.nextInt(2);
        switch(toss){
            case 0 : 
             out.println("tails");
             break;
            case 1 : 
             out.println("heads");
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a break statement after the first case block in order to get the expected behavior. The way switch statement works is that without a break, the control flow executes each statement after the case that matched. This will be the correct code for your case.

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;

class generateRandomNumbers{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random coin = new Random();
        int toss;
        toss = coin.nextInt(2);
        switch(toss){
            case 0 : 
                out.println("tails");
                break;
            case 1 ; out.println("heads");
        }
    }
}
```

Read more about the switch statement works in Java here.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html